# Storing canvas images in array

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have multiple canvases with several layers on it. I need to store all generated images in an array and then display them on page.

```
var final_images = {};
var imageProcessing = function(source, images) {
for (var key in source) {

    switch(key){
        case "one":
        case "two":
        case "three":
        default:
            context.drawImage(images[key], 0, 0, 921, 680);
        case "top_layer":
            context.drawImage(images.top_layer, 0, 0, 921, 57);
        case "badge":
            context.drawImage(images.badge, 700, -20, 175, 175);
    }
}
}
```

Function for loading images.

```
function loadImages(source) {
var images = {};
var loadedImages = 0;
var numImages = 0;
// get num of sources
for (var src in source) {
    numImages++;
}
for (var src in source) {
    images[src] = new Image();
    images[src].onload = function () {
        if (++loadedImages >= numImages) {
            imageProcessing(source, images);
        }
    };
    images[src].src = source[src];
}
}
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

loadImages(source);
```

How can I combine all layers into one image and store it in an array?

Comment: What do you exactly want us to answer? Please specify your question first

Comment: @ashokgct, I edited it. Hope now it is more clear

Comment: Assuming you want to keep the existing canvases separate, create an in memory canvas with `document.createElement('canvas')` and draw each of the layer canvases to it in z-index order with `memContext.drawImage(layer1canvas,0,0) ...`.